# Generic error handling for multiple error type with single generic function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I have a function that handleError for generic type of RebloodError. I have 2 type of enum of error (InitialError and MainError) that conformed RebloodError protocol (which conformed Error protocol). Here is the detail.

InitialError

```
enum InitialError: RebloodError {
    // Some Error Cases inside
}
```

MainError

```
enum MainError: RebloodError {
    // Some Error Cases inside
}
```

RebloodError

```
protocol RebloodError: Error { }
```

The error handler

```
@discardableResult func handleError<T: RebloodError>(_ error: T) -> Bool {
    let title = "Something Might Be Wrong"

    switch error {
    case .anErrorCase:
        presentErrorAlert(title: title, message: "Please Sign In to continue ", completionHandler: {
            // TODO: Go to sign in from here
        })
        return true


    default:
        presentErrorAlert(title: title, message: "Please contact support or try to relaunch the app", completionHandler: {
            exit(0)
        })
        return false
    }
}
```

presentErrorAlert is my custom function to present UIAlertController to show error alert.

**Is there any best way to handle multiple type of error with a generic function in my case?**

Comment: Isn't that what catch statements are for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to add a common interface for your error handling needs to `RebloodError` and implementing that in your concrete error types:

```
protocol RebloodError: Error {
  var alertTitle: String { get }
  var alertMessage: String { get }
  func handle()
}

enum MainError: RebloodError {
  case foo
  case bar

  var alertTitle: String {
    switch self {
    case .foo: return "Foo!"
    case .bar: return "Bar!"
    }
  }      

  var alertMessage: String { ... }

  func handle() {
     switch self {
      case .foo: exit(0)
      default: ()
     }
  }
}
```

In your handling code you can use this interface to get all the info you need, the error will know what to do:

```
func handleError<T: RebloodError>(_ error: T) -> Bool {
  presentErrorAlert(title: error.alertTitle, message: error.alertMessage, completionHandler: { error.handle() })
}
```

The `RebloodError.handle` function of course is limited to performing actions it can do without any context info (e.g. popping a view controller). If you need this things get more complicated: e.g. you could pass some context object into the method (keep in mind that when calling *you don't know* which concrete type it is, so you need a common context interface as well); or let `RebloodError.handle` return a command object which you then interpret in the calling code.

Comment: Thanks @dr_barto it's super helpful